# Mock new object creation Mockito without PowerMock

Tags: mocking, mockito, junit-jupiter

I have a say `SomeResolver` whose method `resolve` I need to test. The method is creating a `new` object which I am trying to `mock`. Something like below

```java
public class SomeResolver {
  public String resolve() {
    // need to mock this
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
   // so that this
   Response response = client.newCall(someRequest).execute();
   // returns a response I want.
   ...
  }
}
```

My Test Class `SomeResolverTest` can mock `final` classes and uses **Mockito v3.9.0** but I cannot add the `Powermock` dependency

Is there a way I can mock the value returned by `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Vitor Cavalcanti is good one but for this specific use case, I am better off using the `mockwebserver` library provided by `OkHttp`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
    <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Because once I keep adding tests I will need to mock a lot of classes related to the web server and this dependency does that for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `mockito-inline` dependency and use `MockedConstruction` to mock new construction of classes.

Take a look here:
https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocked_construction